# Не работает маска ввода MaskedInput

Tags: javascript, html

Маска подключена два раза. Первый раз работает второй - нет. Библиотека подключена правильно.

```
`<input  name="phone" id="phone1" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" class="buy-form__input form-control" required="true">
<script>
//Код jQuery, установливающий маску для ввода телефона элементу input
//1. После загрузки страницы,  когда все элементы будут доступны выполнить...
$(function(){
  //2. Получить элемент, к которому необходимо добавить маску
  $("#phone1").mask("+38(099) 99-99-999");
});
</script>`
```

Этот фрагмент работает!
Следующий нет.

```
 `<input  name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" class="buy-form__input form-control" required="true">
<script>
//Код jQuery, установливающий маску для ввода телефона элементу input
//1. После загрузки страницы,  когда все элементы будут доступны выполнить...
$(function(){
  //2. Получить элемент, к которому необходимо добавить маску
  $("#phone").mask("+38(099) 99-99-999");
});
</script>`
```

Comment: зачем два раза? обращайтесь не по id, а class ` $(".phone").mask("+38(099) 99-99-999");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает, причина явно не в плагине

```html
<input name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" required>
<input name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" required>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script>

  jQuery(function($) {
    $("input[name=phone]").mask("+38(099) 99-99-999");
  });
  
</script>
```